# Access 2007 - Use the Form Wizard to create a form based on an existing form

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2007, templates, forms

I have a form called `frmFormTemplate`, which basically just has a back color and properties for the default controls. What I want to do is when using the Create Form Wizard in Access 2007, make it use the properties from `frmFormTemplate` to style the form.

How can this be achieved? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use the form wizards, but if you set a pointer to your template form in Access options, all forms created without the wizard will inherit your settings. I doubt there's any way to change the default settings of the wizards, as they are likely locked up in an MDE that is not accessible to you.

Why you'd want to use the form wizards, I don't know. They don't produce very good forms.